# 2 active rails apps, 1 apache/passenger server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, capistrano, passenger

Anyone have a good tutorial on how to setup apache & passenger to run two active rails apps at once?  I am trying to get one running on port 80 and the other on port 3001.  I already know how to setup 1 app, but am unsure how to get 2 running at once.

I've found this - http://renderedtext.com/blog/2009/09/14/running-a-rails-app-on-passenger-on-a-different-port/

But that is just getting me half way.  Btw I am also using capistrano if that helps.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed that link, then you are already familiar with virtualhosts. All you need is to create one more virtualhost. Good way to do it is to create one more file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (path to apache may vary) and to put a link to that file into `sites-enabled` folder. In that file you should describe your virtualhost as usual, but specifying a port:

```
<VirtualHost *:3001>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/sites/some_site/current/public
    ServerName sub.domain.ru

#more params here
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to `restart` or `reload` apache to apply effect of changes. 
If that doesn't work, check that you have following lines in your `apache2.conf`:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

Comment: this worked with the exception you need to do the following as well - sudo a2ensite app_name and service apache2 reload then restart

Comment: Great! But a2ensite does the same I describe in `put a link to...`. And 'reload then restart' seems strange - they do similar things: reload is almost restarting - updating config, but not breaking current workflow of working sites.

Comment: Ah ok didn't know that sorry :)